# What installed nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

Something has installed nginx on my system, I have not specfically typed apt-get install nginx.

How can I find what has installed nginx ?

I only noticed after a reboot, the system is rarely rebooted so the timescale is unknown.

I've found it in dpkg.log. But I don't remember installing it and I can't figure out from the list what package required it.

Comment: `dpkg -l "nginx*"` --> for apt and `find / -iname "*nginx*"` -> for non-apt

Comment: Look in the apt logs, I guess. Grepping `/var/log/apt/history.log.i.gz`  should show it if it wasn't too long ago.

Comment: @Faheem add your comment as an answer and I will accept it. I found the command I probably copied and paste a huge apt-get line from some install instructions I can see from the other packages in the line what it was. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the commands:

```
grep nginx /var/log/apt/history.log nginx

grep nginx /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

etc (for whatever `history.log` files are present). The apt history shows what packages were installed by apt, so will show your package as long as it wasn't too long ago. To do these all at one shot, use (thanks to Stephen Kitt):

```
zgrep nginx /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aptitude why <packagename>` to determine why a package that was automatically installed. Here is an example of `pulseaudio` on my system:

```
$ aptitude why pulseaudio
i   pulseaudio            Recommends pulseaudio-module-x11      
i A pulseaudio-module-x11 Depends    pulseaudio (= 4.0-6~bpo7+1)
```

Comment: returns nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply remove it — `apt-get remove nginx` — counting on the fact that APT will complain if some other package depends on it. If there *is* such a dependency, you have your probable culprit. Then you can decide if you really do want to keep it.

If nothing else depended on it, I'd go looking in its web root (probably `/var/log/www`) to see if it was serving something "interesting."

Comment: One could use that with a `-s` test flag to be safe.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I guess that depends on whether you think the `Do you want to continue? [Y/n]` prompt is sufficient to keep you from doing something foolish. Personally, I'd only bother with `-s` in a script.

Comment: I figure better safe than sorry. It's all too easy to hit enter.